How do I stop Windows 10 from downloading and installing Outlook (new)?
Windows 10's task bar calendar is not synchronous with Outlook, it is with old Calendar app. Only way to continue to use old Calendar app is to uninstall Outlook (new). However, it immediately reinstalls Outlook. How can I prevent this and continue to use old Calendar app?

You can use the registry keys and PowerShell controls provided in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/outlook-on-the-web/enable-disable-employee-access-new-outlook

@Soki my computer is personal so I don't have any Exchange Online PowerShell, my local PowerShell does not recognize CASMailbox syntax. Registry keys do not add the toggle to the Outlook app, however, after I uninstall Outlook and can open old Calendar app, I can see the toggle there. Still, it automatically reinstalls Outlook and hides the toggle.

I'm afraid there's no direct way to stop it on personal devices, and I've seen a lot of people experiencing this issue.
I've seen user feedback that this method works.
Similar threads:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-stop-the-new-outlook-from-automatically/34246983-2a13-4462-8a8a-df618c36ca3f?page=2
Reference Code:https://github.com/thepastafarian/New-Outlook-Killer


